# How is the output generated for this java program?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested-loops

Can someone explain the logic of this code? How it works? The output gets printed as 2 3 4 but I don't understand how.. I'm writing these extra lines cause unfortunately stack overflow doesn't let me post the question if there isn't enough explanation about it, which is annoying cause I have come here only to get an explanation for this code. Hope it allows me to post my question now!

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Javaexcercise {
    public static void main(String[] args)

    {

        int[] my_array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4};
        

        for (int i = 0; i < my_array.length-1; i++)

        {

            for (int j = i+1; j < my_array.length; j++)

            {

                if ((my_array[i] == my_array[j]) && (i != j))

                {

                    System.out.println(my_array[j]);

                }

            }

        }

    }   

}
```

Output :

```
2
3
4
```

Comment: Load the code in a debugger and step thought each line of code.

Comment: If you didn't put extra white space between each line, you might not have had to try to "trick" the parser.

Comment: *"I'm writing these extra lines cause ..."* This means you know your question doesn't meet Stack Overflow's standards but you didn't try to improve it. Perhaps you could have said which parts of the code you *do* understand, or where the code came from, or what you think the purpose of the code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program will compare the values for every pair in the array and print only the matches.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through each index in the array

```
for (int i = 0; i < my_array.length-1; i++)
```

For each index, iterate through the indices that follow it

```
    for (int j = i+1; j < my_array.length; j++)
```

If the values in the array at the two indices are the same

```
        if ((my_array[i] == my_array[j]) && (i != j))
```

Print the value

```
            System.out.println(my_array[j]);
```

So you'll get the first item in any matching pairs printed.

Note that the `i != j` clause is redundant and can be removed because `j` starts at `i + 1`.

Comment: yes I understand that but how does this print out 2 3 4 ?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I just explained why it prints the duplicates in my answer.